# Zend_Pdf adding Verdana font to PDF

Tags: php, zend-framework, fonts, magento-1.9

I'm creating magento extension for pdf generating. I need to use Verdana Bold,Verdana Reg... fonts to my pdf file which generated using Zend_Pdf. Anyone can explain how to use the proper path for accessing TTF type fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this first you should upload desired font files into a directory best place to upload a font is inside `lib` folder so in this demonstration I will use create directory inside `lib` folder called `customfonts` and upload my font file there

Now call it on desired php file (ex: inside Shipment.php) and use it like below

```
$chevinFontBold = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/customfonts/chevin-bold.ttf');

$page->setFont($chevinFontBold, 8);
```

here 8 is the font size

Comment: This is what I expected answer. It works. Thanks a lot... I didn't know where to place the font and the way to get correct path. Great work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
//load font from file system

    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath("/path/to/myfont.ttf");

    //add $font to page

    $page->setFont($font, $fontSize);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried it. But I have some confusion with how to put path, Eg: I copied the font files to my folder 'XXXX' which contained php code. From there I need to call the font. Is it possible???